# nginx proxy request to service with header value from an authentication http request

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

This is what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

I want to use nginx as a classic reverse proxy to expose server's resources.
Before calling the server, nginx should ask a token to the token issuer (an internal service) and inject this token into the authentication header of the call towards the server.

Is it possibile to achieve this with nginx?
I looked around inside the nginx documentation and I know I can use `proxy_set_header` to modify the headers being proxied to the server.

**Update**

I was able to make the solution below work;
[here is a POC on github](https://github.com/theliuk/poc-nginx-reverse-proxy-auth)

Comment: Check the [ngx_http_auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) module.

Comment: I don't find an example in which I take the response from the subrequest and "inject" it into the proxied request.

Comment: How does the token issuer returns the token? In the response body or via some HTTP header? In second case you can use the [`auth_request_set`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request_set) directive.

Comment: That's up to me. I'd prefer to keep it in the body, but I can still live with the fact it is returned as part of the response header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can make your token issuer to return the token via some HTTP header, for example the `X-JWT-Token`, here is an example that should work for you:

```
location /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://token-issuer;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length 0;
    # You can pass an additional data for the token issuer, for example
    # proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
location / {
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $token $upstream_http_x_jwt_token;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $token";
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
}
```

Comment: It works; what if I'd like the token to be returned inside the token-issuer body?

Comment: @LucaMarzi I don't know if it is possible with the vanilla nginx at all (if you'd manage to find such solution, please share it with the others). It can be possible with the third party modules that support subrequests (using [njs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/) via [`ngx_http_js_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html) ([example](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/examples.html#subrequest)) or via [`lua-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) using the [`ngx.location.capture`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture) function).

Comment: I created this [POC on github](https://github.com/theliuk/poc-nginx-reverse-proxy-auth) to test the solution above.